# How to change left margin in a res based resume

Tags: formatting, cv, resume

I am interested in using [this resume](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res1.pdf). How can I change the left margin of paragraphs in each section?

For example, in the "JOB OBJECTIVE" section, I want "A summer..." to move a little to the left and the letter "A" which currently is under letter "B" of "OBJECTIVE" to move under letter "O" of "OBJECTIVE".

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{res} 

\begin{document} 
\name{HAROLD C. GOODBETTER\\[12pt]}

\address{\bf  PRESENT ADDRESS\\193 5th Avenue\\Troy, NY 12180\\(518) 274-1234}
\address{\bf PERMANENT ADDRESS \\ 110 Brant Avenue \\  Upper Saddle
         River,   NJ 07458 \\  (201) 555-9509}

\begin{resume}
\section{JOB OBJECTIVE}          
    A summer position that will use my accounting and computer
    skills.          

\section{EDUCATION}          
    Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY\\        
    Bachelor of Science, Management, May 1990\\       
    Concentration in Management Systems\\   
    Minors in Computer Science and Economics\\        
    G.P.A. 3.3/4.0 
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without knowing how you produce your resume (which class/template?) it will be impossible to tell what to change to get another indentation. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `\sectionwidth`. The `res` class provides an own command for that task, `\newsectionwidth`, which takes care about all the other lengths that depend on the `\sectionwidth`:

```
\documentclass{res} 

\newsectionwidth{27.5pt}

\begin{document} 
\name{HAROLD C. GOODBETTER\\[12pt]}

\address{\bfseries  PRESENT ADDRESS\\193 5th Avenue\\Troy, NY 12180\\(518) 274-1234}
\address{\bfseries PERMANENT ADDRESS \\ 110 Brant Avenue \\  Upper Saddle
         River,   NJ 07458 \\  (201) 555-9509}

\begin{resume}
\section{JOB OBJECTIVE}          
    A summer position that will use my accounting and computer
    skills.          

\section{EDUCATION}          
    Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY\\        
    Bachelor of Science, Management, May 1990\\       
    Concentration in Management Systems\\   
    Minors in Computer Science and Economics\\        
    G.P.A. 3.3/4.0 
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: thank you so much for the help, this is exactly what I was looking for.